# Trick Web Design (Full Screen & Non Full Screen Elements)

Tags: html, css

**UPDATE**

After doing some testing and localhost modifications I have found out what I need:

The website must not be scrollable, only the content area.

When zooming the sidebar height should stay consistently to the bottom of the page.

The header must also zoom in and out but remain full width

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dkx2q/2/

Something like this maybe:

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
}
#container{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#fullScreenImage{
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgb(124,197,118);
    position:relative;
}
#content{
    float:left;
    width:75%;
    height:100%;
}
#header{
    display:block;
    height:15%;
    background-color:rgb(94,142,178);
    position:relative;
}
#sidebar{
    float:left;
    height:85%;
    width:20%;
    background-color:rgb(162,94,179);
    position:relative;
}
#contentArea{
    float:left;
    width:80%;
    height:85%;
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
    position:relative;
}
span{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    width:100%;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Helvetica, 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial Block', Arial;
    font-size:9em;
    text-align:center;
}
#header span{
    font-size:7em;
    top:40%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id='container'>
        <div id='fullScreenImage'><span>Full Screen Image</span>
        </div>
        <div id='content'>
            <div id='header'><span>Header</span></div>
            <div id='sidebar'>
                <span>Sidebar</span>
            </div>
            <div id='contentArea'><span>Content Area</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `html, body {height:100%}` was missing. http://jsfiddle.net/dkx2q/2/ It works on your website because it's rendering in quicks mode (no doctype defined)

Comment: Thanks!! I'm used to operating inside of a framework with things like body attributes and doctype already defined, its definitely something I need to work on.

Comment: This kind of works. http://i.imgur.com/JLMsUcl.png < I am still having issues trying to get this image to stay fullscreen no matter what content is there. The sidebar and content areas have to stay 100% automatic heights and I cannot figure this out. You did basically what I have done, too in your code. Any ideas?

Comment: bfred.it - Height on body worked well for the content area. How do I make sure this entire site is a fullscreen based website but with the same layout and no dragging of content? Only the content area can scroll and no where else I've come to see.

Comment: I adjusted the sidebar and removed the auto height / 100% height completely and this solves the issue with it actually stretching with content.